# Django CSRF Verification Failed Despite Correct Token

Tags: django, vue.js, axios, django-csrf

I'm having trouble with CSRF verification in Django. Despite including the correct CSRF token in my POST requests and following all the recommended steps in the Django documentation, I keep getting a "CSRF Missing" error.

Here are my Axios and Django configurations.

```
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  timeout: 4000,
  withCredentials: true,
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
});

...

headers: {
      'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
    },
```

```
# settings.py
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'X-CSRFToken'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http:127.0.0.1:5173'
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def get_csrf_token(request):
    request.META["CSRF_COOKIE_USED"] = True
    return JsonResponse({'msg': 'now csrftoken has been set in ur Cookies'})
```

When I send a POST request, the request headers already include the required `X-CSRFToken` and `Cookie`
`
, but I still receive a 403 response.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Ensuring that the CSRF token as an X-CSRFToken header
- Checking that my browser is not blocking third-party cookies
- Changing the CSRF cookie name in my Django settings

None of these solutions have worked for me. Does anyone have any other suggestions or ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can acquire the token like this:

First create a **csrf_token.js** file with this code:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === name + "=") {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
const CSRF_TOKEN = getCookie("csrftoken");

export { CSRF_TOKEN };
```

Then in your axios configuration file import **CSRF_TOKEN** and use it like this.

```
import { CSRF_TOKEN } from "path_where_file_is/csrf_token.js";

const service =  axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://example.com",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "X-CSRFTOKEN": CSRF_TOKEN,
  },
});
```

To know more checkout django official documentation **How to use Django’s CSRF protection**. [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/)